# Why my Procedure with CONCAT show me a NULL value?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, string-concatenation

I'm trying to run this code on MySQL WorkBench:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE lavoratore_superficie(IN _superficie CHAR(5), 
                    OUT codiciFiscali VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    
    DECLARE finito INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE codiceFiscale VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
    
    DECLARE cursoreCodici CURSOR FOR
        SELECT distinct(TL.Capocantiere)
            FROM superficie SU INNER JOIN lottomateriale LM on SU.Codice = LM.Superficie INNER JOIN lavoro LA ON LM.Lavoro = LA.Codice INNER JOIN divisionelavoro DT ON DT.Lavoro = LA.Codice
            INNER JOIN turno TU ON TU.Codice = DT.Turno INNER JOIN turnolavoro TL ON TL.Turno = DT.Turno
            WHERE SU.Codice = _superficie;
            
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER
        FOR NOT FOUND SET finito = 1;
        
    OPEN cursoreCodici;
    
    preleva: LOOP
        FETCH cursoreCodici INTO codiceFiscale;
        IF finito = 1 THEN
            LEAVE preleva;
        END IF;
        SET codiciFiscali = CONCAT(codiceFiscale, ';', codiciFiscali);
    END LOOP preleva;
    
    CLOSE cursoreCodici;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then I try to visualize the result set of my query into a local variable with the CONCAT function:

```
SET @codiciFiscali = '';
CALL lavoratore_superficie('SU001', @codiciFiscali);
SELECT @codiciFiscali;
```

But after the CALL if I select @codiciFiscali the result set is NULL.

Comment: What is this procedure doing that `GROUP_CONCAT(distinct TL.Capocantiere separator ';')` doesn't do?

Answer (score 0):

Since `codiciFiscali` is declared as an `OUT` parameter, the initial value of `@codiciFiscali` is not being passed to the procedure. So the variable defaults to `NULL`.

Either add

```
SET codiciFiscali = '';
```

before the loop, or change the parameter to `INOUT` so it will concatenate to the caller's value.

Comment: Sorry I was taken for granted but the code complete was: SET @codiciFiscali = '';
CALL lavoratore_superficie('SU001', @codiciFiscali);
SELECT @codiciFiscali;